# Traer todos los datos de una tabla en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  pr_production_units_details.id AS idProductionUnit, pr_production_units_details.production_units_detail AS  productionUnit, pr_varieties.variety
FROM (SELECT MAX(sw_sowing.id) AS id
            FROM sw_sowing
            WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
            AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = 1
            AND YEARWEEK(sw_sowing.date) <= 201741
            GROUP BY  sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
)AS sw
INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
INNER JOIN pr_production_units_details ON pr_production_units_details.id = sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = sw_sowing.id_variety
WHERE pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail = 13
GROUP BY pr_production_units_details.id, variety
```

Aquí traigo las variedades sembradas en cada unidad, lo que pasa es que me trae únicamente las unidades que tienen variedades sembradas.

Lo que necesito es traer todas las unidades sin importar que no tengan variedades, lo intenté con un LEFT JOIN pero no me funciona.

Estas son las estructuras de las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sw_sowing` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_production_unit_detail` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_variety` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
  `id_tenant` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

  INSERT INTO `sw_sowing` (`id`, `id_production_unit_detail`, `id_variety`, `date`, `status`, `id_tenant`) VALUES
(8904, 1552, 3, '2014-01-03', 100, 1),
(8905, 1554, 3, '2014-01-03', 100, 1),
(8906, 1556, 3, '2014-01-03', 100, 1),
(8907, 1558, 3, '2014-01-03', 100, 1),
(8908, 1560, 3, '2014-01-03', 100, 1),
(8967, 1609, 4, '2008-06-23', 100, 1),
(8981, 1567, 12, '2009-07-13', 100, 1),
(8992, 1571, 1, '2008-08-11', 100, 1),
(8993, 1573, 1, '2008-08-11', 100, 1),
(8994, 1593, 1, '2008-08-11', 100, 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pr_production_units_details` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_production_unit` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_grouper_detail` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `production_units_detail` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `area` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
  `id_tenant` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

  INSERT INTO `pr_production_units_details` (`id`, `id_production_unit`, `id_grouper_detail`, `production_units_detail`, `area`, `status`, `id_tenant`) VALUES
(1491, 1, 13, 1, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1492, 1, 13, 2, 18.45, 100, 1),
(1493, 1, 13, 3, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1494, 1, 13, 4, 18.45, 100, 1),
(1495, 1, 13, 5, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1496, 1, 13, 6, 18.45, 100, 1),
(1497, 1, 13, 7, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1498, 1, 13, 8, 18.45, 100, 1),
(1499, 1, 13, 9, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1500, 1, 13, 10, 18.45, 100, 1),
(1501, 1, 13, 11, 4.14, 100, 1),
(1502, 1, 13, 12, 25.20, 100, 1),
(1503, 1, 13, 13, 4.14, 100, 1),
(1504, 1, 13, 14, 25.20, 100, 1),
(1505, 1, 13, 15, 4.14, 100, 1),
(1506, 1, 13, 16, 25.20, 100, 1),
(1507, 1, 13, 17, 4.14, 100, 1),
(1508, 1, 13, 18, 25.20, 100, 1),
(1509, 1, 13, 19, 4.14, 100, 1),
(1510, 1, 13, 20, 25.20, 100, 1),
(1511, 1, 13, 21, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1512, 1, 13, 22, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1513, 1, 13, 23, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1514, 1, 13, 24, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1515, 1, 13, 25, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1516, 1, 13, 26, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1517, 1, 13, 27, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1518, 1, 13, 28, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1519, 1, 13, 29, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1520, 1, 13, 30, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1521, 1, 13, 31, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1522, 1, 13, 32, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1523, 1, 13, 33, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1524, 1, 13, 34, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1525, 1, 13, 35, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1526, 1, 13, 36, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1527, 1, 13, 37, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1528, 1, 13, 38, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1529, 1, 13, 39, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1530, 1, 13, 40, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1531, 1, 13, 41, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1532, 1, 13, 42, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1533, 1, 13, 43, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1534, 1, 13, 44, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1535, 1, 13, 45, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1536, 1, 13, 46, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1537, 1, 13, 47, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1538, 1, 13, 48, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1539, 1, 13, 49, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1540, 1, 13, 50, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1541, 1, 13, 51, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1542, 1, 13, 52, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1543, 1, 13, 53, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1544, 1, 13, 54, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1545, 1, 13, 55, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1546, 1, 13, 56, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1547, 1, 13, 57, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1548, 1, 13, 58, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1549, 1, 13, 59, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1550, 1, 13, 60, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1551, 1, 13, 61, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1552, 1, 13, 62, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1553, 1, 13, 63, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1554, 1, 13, 64, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1555, 1, 13, 65, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1556, 1, 13, 66, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1557, 1, 13, 67, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1558, 1, 13, 68, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1559, 1, 13, 69, 0.00, 100, 1),
(1560, 1, 13, 70, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1561, 1, 13, 71, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1562, 1, 13, 72, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1563, 1, 13, 73, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1564, 1, 13, 74, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1565, 1, 13, 75, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1566, 1, 13, 76, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1567, 1, 13, 77, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1568, 1, 13, 78, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1569, 1, 13, 79, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1570, 1, 13, 80, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1571, 1, 13, 81, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1572, 1, 13, 82, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1573, 1, 13, 83, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1574, 1, 13, 84, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1575, 1, 13, 85, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1576, 1, 13, 86, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1577, 1, 13, 87, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1578, 1, 13, 88, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1579, 1, 13, 89, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1580, 1, 13, 90, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1581, 1, 13, 91, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1582, 1, 13, 92, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1583, 1, 13, 93, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1584, 1, 13, 94, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1585, 1, 13, 95, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1586, 1, 13, 96, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1587, 1, 13, 97, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1588, 1, 13, 98, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1589, 1, 13, 99, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1590, 1, 13, 100, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1591, 1, 13, 101, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1592, 1, 13, 102, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1593, 1, 13, 103, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1594, 1, 13, 104, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1595, 1, 13, 105, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1596, 1, 13, 106, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1597, 1, 13, 107, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1598, 1, 13, 108, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1599, 1, 13, 109, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1600, 1, 13, 110, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1601, 1, 13, 111, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1602, 1, 13, 112, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1603, 1, 13, 113, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1604, 1, 13, 114, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1605, 1, 13, 115, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1606, 1, 13, 116, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1607, 1, 13, 117, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1608, 1, 13, 118, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1609, 1, 13, 119, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1610, 1, 13, 120, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1611, 1, 13, 121, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1612, 1, 13, 122, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1613, 1, 13, 123, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1614, 1, 13, 124, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1615, 1, 13, 125, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1616, 1, 13, 126, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1617, 1, 13, 127, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1618, 1, 13, 128, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1619, 1, 13, 129, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1620, 1, 13, 130, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1621, 1, 13, 131, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1622, 1, 13, 132, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1623, 1, 13, 133, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1624, 1, 13, 134, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1625, 1, 13, 135, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1626, 1, 13, 136, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1627, 1, 13, 137, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1628, 1, 13, 138, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1629, 1, 13, 139, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1630, 1, 13, 140, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1631, 1, 13, 141, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1632, 1, 13, 142, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1633, 1, 13, 143, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1634, 1, 13, 144, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1635, 1, 13, 145, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1636, 1, 13, 146, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1637, 1, 13, 147, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1638, 1, 13, 148, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1639, 1, 13, 149, 28.80, 100, 1),
(1640, 1, 13, 150, 28.80, 100, 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pr_varieties` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `variety` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

  INSERT INTO `pr_varieties` (`id`, `variety`) VALUES
(1, 'COTE D AZUR'),
(2, 'CHERRY BAY'),
(3, 'SALMON BAY'),
(4, 'VIRGINIA'),
(5, 'ORANGE QUEEN'),
(6, 'PRIMADONNA'),
(8, 'SENNA'),
(12, 'VERDI'),
(14, 'SIBERIA'),
(16, 'VOYAGER'),
(17, 'ANASTACIA'),
(18, 'PATAGONIA'),
(19, 'HAWAIIAN DREAM'),
(20, 'KIMBERLY'),
(23, 'LUCERO'),
(24, 'NADYA'),
(26, 'ANNA'),
(29, 'HAPPY FEET'),
(30, 'MONTE VECCHIO'),
(32, 'FLORIANO'),
(34, 'COCKTAIL'),
(35, 'BARBADOS'),
(39, 'ISTANBUL'),
(40, 'HERCULES'),
(41, 'MONTE LAVA'),
(42, 'ROME'),
(44, 'PALERMO'),
(46, 'SET POINT'),
(47, 'CARTAGENA'),
(50, 'NATALYA'),
(52, 'K2'),
(54, 'MARIAM'),
(55, 'ARIEL'),
(56, 'ALESSO'),
(66, 'M 45'),
(85, 'TONATIUH'),
(132, 'R 1733'),
(144, 'R 1687'),
(148, 'CLEO');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabian, antes que nada se agradece una pregunta bien alineada con el principio de "mínimo, completo y verificable".

Si no entendí mal tu pregunta y las estructuras de negocio, lo que necesitas en primer lugar es obtener el último `sw_sowing.id` por `id_production_unit_detail`, que puedes hacerlo así:

```
SELECT sw1.id_production_unit_detail,
                   sw1.id_variety
            FROM sw_sowing sw1
            INNER JOIN ( SELECT id_production_unit_detail,
                                MAX(sw_sowing.id) AS id
                                FROM sw_sowing 
                                WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
                                      AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = 1
                                      AND YEARWEEK(sw_sowing.date) <= 201741
                                GROUP BY  sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
                        ) sw2
                        ON sw1.id = sw2.id
                        AND sw1.id_production_unit_detail = sw2.id_production_unit_detail
```

Luego, sí debieras hacer un `LEFT`  a esta consulta y otro `LEFT` a `pr_varieties`, lo cual terminaría quedando así:

```
SELECT  pr_production_units_details.id AS idProductionUnit, 
        pr_production_units_details.production_units_detail AS  productionUnit,
        pr_varieties.variety
FROM pr_production_units_details
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sw1.id_production_unit_detail,
                   sw1.id_variety
            FROM sw_sowing sw1
            INNER JOIN ( SELECT id_production_unit_detail,
                                MAX(sw_sowing.id) AS id
                                FROM sw_sowing 
                                WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
                                      AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = 1
                                      AND YEARWEEK(sw_sowing.date) <= 201741
                                GROUP BY  sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
                        ) sw2
                        ON sw1.id = sw2.id
                        AND sw1.id_production_unit_detail = sw2.id_production_unit_detail
         ) sw 
         ON sw.id_production_unit_detail = pr_production_units_details.id
LEFT JOIN pr_varieties
  ON pr_varieties.id = sw.id_variety
WHERE pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail = 13
ORDER BY pr_production_units_details.id;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Seguiré las reglas para hacer las preguntas

Comment: @FabianSierra, por la dudas, mi comentario inicial, fue porque tu pregunta estaba justamente muy bien formulada. Saludos.